# i get this error You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error. what to do

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

when i run my angular Project it showing error

Answer I want, resolve this

Answer (score 2):

In your **package.json** file, can you verify if the line ***angular/core*** is added as a dependency like this?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Above sample is showing it depends on ***v13.3***.

```
"@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
```

Also, it can likely denote broken node packages folder, remove node_modules and try,

```
npm install
```

as well. And restart the server once again. That can likely fix it.